# Laravel Eloquent Model, add query to ->get() function

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i want to overwrite the get function in my Customer Model.

```
 public function get(array $options = [])
 {
   $user = \Auth::user();

   if($user->role_id == 1){
     return parent::get();

   }else if($user->role_id == 4){
     return parent::where("user_id", $user->id)->get();

   }else if($user->role_id == 3){
     $users = User::where("user_id", $user->id)->get();

     return parent::where("user_id", $user->id)->orWhereIn('user_id', $users)->get();
   }
  }
```

Is this possible ?

Comment: What do you mean? The get function basically runs the query. Are you wanting to manipulate the output? Please provide a bit more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is `global scopes`

> Global scopes allow you to add constraints to all queries for a given
>   model. Laravel's own soft delete functionality utilizes global scopes
>   to only pull "non-deleted" models from the database. Writing your own
>   global scopes can provide a convenient, easy way to make sure every
>   query for a given model receives certain constraints.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#query-scopes

Comment: thank you for your answer. i think it could work with scopes but now when i try to add a whereIn Query i get this error

        $builder->where("user_id", $user->id)->orWhereIn('user_id', $users)->get();

Out of memory (allocated 16777216) (tried to allocate 917504 bytes)

php.ini:
memory_limit = 600M

Comment: Set toSql() insted of get() and dd() the result. It should put some light on whats going on with your query

Comment: @CemFlav, whereIn accepts an array of items, I think you need to pass an array of Ids instead of a collection of objects. Try plucking the Id from the users before passing the data to the whereIn function.